# Using yago/yago2 with python

Tags: python, memory

I have been researching about yago but cannot seem to find much material on it.

In uncompressed formatt it is 97 GB.(Way more than my memory).

Is there anyway i could fire yago queries to extract the information from yago?

Comment: Try https://github.com/bowdenk7/yago

Comment: This is a long shot. Is there any updates on this?